# Confused about short exact sequence involving $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ and $\mathcal{O}_Z$ for $\pi:Z\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ closed embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

If $\pi: Z\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ is a closed embedding where $Z$ is the zero set of some degree homogeneous polynomial, we have:

$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-d)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Z\rightarrow 0$$

where we think $\mathcal{O}_Z$ is really $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_Z$.

Because of this pushforward, I am confused how this short exact sequence interacts with tensoring with $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$.

Isn't $\mathcal{O}_Z(1)$ defined to be $\pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$, does that make $(\pi_*\mathcal{O}_Z )\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m)$ equal to $\pi_*(\pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))^{\otimes m}$, so we can say that

$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-d+m)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Z(m)\rightarrow 0.$$

I am pretty confused about all this, but hopefully this makes enough sense that I can get some feedback.

Thank you for any help or advice

Comment: My question seems to be answered by Prop 5.12 in Chapter III of Hartshorne

Comment: Too much time has passed for me to edit. I meant chapter II in Hartshorne (not in chapter III)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the second exact sequence from the 1st, just tensor up with $\mathcal{O}(m)$, we get $$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-d) \otimes \mathcal{O}(m) \rightarrow \mathcal{O} \otimes \mathcal{O}(m) \rightarrow (\pi_* \mathcal{O}_Z) \otimes \mathcal{O}(m) \rightarrow 0.$$Now, if I understand your question, you want to define $\mathcal{O}_Z(m)$ to be $\pi^* \mathcal{O}(m)$, so you want to know if $(\pi_* \mathcal{O}_Z) \otimes \mathcal{O}(m) \simeq \pi_* \pi^* \mathcal{O}(m).$ Here's a down to earth way to see this: if $Z$ was cut out by $f$, then on each standard affine chart $U_i$, both sides are just $k[U_i]/f(x_0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, x_n)$, where 1 is in the $i^{th}$ position, and both sides have the same transition functions from $U_i \rightarrow U_j$ (I'm using that you can glue coherent sheaves via identifications satisfying the cocycle condition, and that morphisms defined locally which are compatible on overlaps glue to a global morphism).